# Getting error while installing backend dependencies for spacy

Tags: python, pip, installation, spacy

I am trying to install spacy on python virtual environment. 
My platform is Windows 10. After activating my virtual environment, I am using pip-

```
pip install -U spacy
```

Here is the error that I am getting:
at step- Installing backend dependencies

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\myenv\scripts\python.exe'
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip'
>   install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
>   'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2gxeo4kh\normal'
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0' 'cython>=0.25'
>   wheel 'thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1' 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2'
>   'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2'

I tried upgrading pip to latest version, deleting cache, trying to install wheels independently(getting 'not a supported wheel on this platform' error).

I am getting error at  **Running setup.py install for blis: started Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'**
Here is the full log:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\scripts\python.exe'
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\lib\site-packages\pip'
>   install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
>   'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7eropvdx\normal'
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython>=0.25' 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0'
>   'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2' 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2' wheel
>   'thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1'
>          cwd: None   Complete output (62 lines):   Collecting cython>=0.25
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/08/4f0d09d63b713955f9c6937923f1b1432331f468912b65824b19b9d82d19/Cython-0.29.13-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   (1.6MB)   Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e9/411be1845f1ac07ae3bc40a4b19ba401819baed4fa63b4f5ef28b2300eb4/murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz
>   Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/cb/4ff546a491f764f67284572d25c57927e3f17103adf979bc99d90128f3eb/cymem-2.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/14/de231123ddbe0bf12bd9b1993122d67f22859643bee4dad3b6ce91986336/preshed-3.0.2.tar.gz
>   (167kB)   Collecting wheel
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/13/fe9cbdc0a97578d13063352ecc9cc3d1e0dda2e59aa68cc91428b2a1b106/thinc-7.1.1.tar.gz
>   (1.9MB)   Collecting blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1)
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/5a/f9b8a78e3d1fdde1b0215413d88ab55d907ab81f95b62418a6e9cda30dec/blis-0.4.1.tar.gz
>   (1.8MB)   Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1)
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/c1/d76ccdd12c716be79162d934fe7de4ac8a318b9302864716dde940641a79/wasabi-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1)
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/63/b68061954228346cbab2c41adb36339678605c47da016f5c71c7ef65f510/srsly-0.1.0.tar.gz
>   (186kB)   Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1)
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/ce/36f9b4fbc7e675a7c8a3809dd5902e24cecfcdbc006e8a7b2417c2b830a2/numpy-1.17.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   (10.8MB)   Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1)
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1)
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/c1/bc1dba38b48f4ae3c4428aea669c5e27bd5a7642a74c8348451e0bd8ff86/tqdm-4.36.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (52kB)   Installing collected packages: cython, murmurhash, cymem,
>   preshed, wheel, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
>       Running setup.py install for murmurhash: started
>         Running setup.py install for murmurhash: finished with status 'done'
>       Running setup.py install for preshed: started
>         Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'done'
>       Running setup.py install for blis: started
>         Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
>         ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>          command: 'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c
>   'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v80ehmnh\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7eropvdx\normal'
>   --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\include\site\python3.7\blis'
>              cwd: C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\
>         Complete output (25 lines):
>         BLIS_COMPILER? None
>         running install
>         running build
>         running build_py
>         creating build
>         creating build\lib.win32-3.7
>         creating build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         copying blis__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         creating build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
>         copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         copying blis__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
>         running build_ext
>         msvc
>         py_compiler msvc
>         {'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_AUTHOR': 'Matthew Honnibal', 'LIB': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64;',
>   'VS100COMNTOOLS': 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\Tools\', 'APPVEYOR_PROJECT_NAME': 'cython-blis', 'AVVM_DOWNLOAD_URL':
>   'https://appveyordownloads.blob.core.windows.net/avvm',
>   'GIT_LFS_PATH': 'C:\Program Files\Git LFS', 'MSYSTEM_CHOST':
>   'x86_64-pc-msys', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL':
>   'honnibal+gh@gmail.com', 'WINDOWSSDK_EXECUTABLEPATH_X64': 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1
>   Tools\x64\', 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\windows', 'LASTEXITCODE': '0',
>   'CHOCOLATEYLASTPATHUPDATE': 'Sun Feb  3 19:40:40 2019', 'INFOPATH':
>   'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\info;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\share\info;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\info;C:\Program Files\Git\share\info', 'SHELL':
>   'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe', 'MSYSTEM_CARCH':
>   'x86_64', 'MSYS2_PATH_TYPE': 'inherit', 'MANPATH': 'C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\local\man;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\share\man;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\man;C:\Program Files\Git\share\man', 'JAVA_HOME':
>   'C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0', 'CI_WINDOWS': 'True',
>   'APPVEYOR_BUILD_AGENT_HYPERV_NIC_CONFIGURED': 'true',
>   'WINDOWSLIBPATH': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\UnionMetadata;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe',
>   'WINDIR': 'C:\windows', 'RANLIB': 'echo', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT':
>   '8bbf4b332e237459bb8f45dc9414b3049a202939', 'VS90COMNTOOLS':
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\Tools\', 'ENABLENUGETPACKAGERESTORE': 'true', 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console', 'CONFIG_SITE': 'C:/Program
>   Files/Git/etc/config.site', 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:', 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:',
>   'HOSTNAME': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'APPVEYOR': 'True', 'FRAMEWORKVERSION64':
>   'v4.0.30319', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'OS': 'Windows_NT',
>   'FSHARPINSTALLDIR': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\', 'WINDOWSSDK_EXECUTABLEPATH_X86':
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX
>   4.6.1 Tools\', 'GOROOT': 'C:\go', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE': 'Visual Studio 2015', 'CI_LINUX': 'False', 'UCRTVERSION':
>   '10.0.14393.0', 'APPVEYOR_API_URL': 'http://localhost:1033/', 'TEMP':
>   'C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1', 'SHLVL': '1',
>   'APPVEYOR_REPO_NAME': 'explosion/cython-blis',
>   'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files',
>   'APR_ICONV_PATH': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\iconv',
>   'HOMEPATH': '\Users\appveyor', 'VISUALSTUDIOVERSION': '14.0',
>   'M2_HOME': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\Maven', 'WINDOWSSDKDIR':
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\', 'FRAMEWORKDIR64':
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64', 'LOGONSERVER':
>   '\\APPVYR-WIN', 'APPVEYOR_JOB_ID': 'wp7dj9edlg7t43xq',
>   'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': 'C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\lib\pkgconfig;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\share\pkgconfig;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\lib\pkgconfig', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_PROVIDER': 'gitHub', '_':
>   'C:/Python27/python', 'APPVEYOR_URL': 'https://ci.appveyor.com',
>   'OPENSSL_CONF': 'C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg', 'APPDATA':
>   'C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Roaming', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH':
>   'update-blis', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_ID': '23072639', 'WIX': 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\', 'FRAMEWORKVERSION': 'v4.0.30319',
>   'TMP': 'C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1', 'COMPUTERNAME':
>   'APPVYR-WIN', 'VS110COMNTOOLS': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\', 'WINDOWSSDKLIBVERSION':
>   '10.0.14393.0\', 'USERDOMAIN': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'VSSDK120INSTALL':
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\',
>   'ORIGINAL_TMP': 'C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1',
>   'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files',
>   'VSSDK140INSTALL': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VSSDK\', 'HOME': 'C:\Users\appveyor', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'CODECONTRACTSINSTALLDIR': 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\', 'FRAMEWORK40VERSION': 'v4.0',
>   'MSYSTEM_PREFIX': 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr',
>   'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'x86', 'CHOCOLATEYINSTALL':
>   'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\ProgramData',
>   'TMPDIR': 'C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1',
>   'APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER': '483', 'FRAMEWORKDIR':
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64', 'PROGRAMW6432':
>   'C:\Program Files', 'USERNAME': 'appveyor', 'CI': 'True', 'PROMPT':
>   '$P$G', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP':
>   '2019-03-14T13:33:06.0000000Z', 'CC': 'clang',
>   'USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'PATHEXT':
>   '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.CPL',
>   'ORIGINAL_TEMP': 'C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1',
>   'APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER': 'C:\projects\cython-blis-h674r', 'XUNIT20':
>   'C:\Tools\xUnit20', 'APPVEYOR_PROJECT_ID': '484208',
>   'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '2', 'ERLANG_HOME': 'C:\Program
>   Files\erl9.2', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432': 'AMD64', 'PUBLIC':
>   'C:\Users\Public', 'WINDOWSSDKVERSION': '10.0.14393.0\',
>   'USERPROFILE': 'C:\Users\appveyor', 'PSMODULEPATH':
>   'C:\Users\appveyor\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\appveyor\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program
>   Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Modules;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS
>   Tools\PowerShell;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\',
>   'VS140COMNTOOLS': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\Tools\', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG': 'false', 'APPVEYOR_PROJECT_SLUG': 'cython-blis-h674r', 'LIBPATH':
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;',
>   'ORIGINAL_PATH': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance
>   Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1
>   Tools\x64;C:\Program
>   Files\LLVM\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer;C:\Tools\GitVersion;C:\Tools\PsTools;C:\Program
>   Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\Tools\WebDriver;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Tools\NUnit\bin;C:\Tools\xUnit;C:\Tools\MSpec;C:\Tools\Coverity\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\go\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\iojs;C:\Program
>   Files\iojs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;C:\Tools\NuGet;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache\Maven\bin;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Tools\NUnit3;C:\Program
>   Files\Mercurial;C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet;C:\Tools\curl\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\AWSCLI;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140;C:\Tools\vcpkg;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\erl9.2\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NSIS;C:\Tools\Octopus;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service
>   Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Service
>   Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program
>   Files\LLVM\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\PowerShell\6;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\appveyor\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent;C:\blis\lib', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER':
>   'Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel',
>   'COMMANDPROMPTTYPE': 'Native', 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '3f02', 'MAVEN_HOME': 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache\Maven', 'PATH': 'C:\Users\appveyor\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\opt\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance
>   Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1
>   Tools\x64;C:\Program
>   Files\LLVM\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer;C:\Tools\GitVersion;C:\Tools\PsTools;C:\Program
>   Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\Tools\WebDriver;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Tools\NUnit\bin;C:\Tools\xUnit;C:\Tools\MSpec;C:\Tools\Coverity\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\go\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\iojs;C:\Program
>   Files\iojs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;C:\Tools\NuGet;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache\Maven\bin;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Tools\NUnit3;C:\Program
>   Files\Mercurial;C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet;C:\Tools\curl\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\AWSCLI;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140;C:\Tools\vcpkg;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program
>   Files\erl9.2\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NSIS;C:\Tools\Octopus;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service
>   Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Service
>   Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program
>   Files\LLVM\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\PowerShell\6;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\appveyor\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent;C:\blis\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl', 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)', 'TERM': 'cygwin', 'PS1':
>   '\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h
>   \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM
>   \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$ ',
>   'INCLUDE': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt;',
>   'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_MESSAGE': 'Fiddle with appveyor',
>   'VS120COMNTOOLS': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\Tools\', 'NETFXSDKDIR': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\', 'VSINSTALLDIR': 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\', 'PLATFORM': 'X64',
>   'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local',
>   'EXTENSIONSDKDIR': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION': '1.0.483',
>   'APPVEYOR_REPO_SCM': 'git', 'MSYSTEM': 'MSYS', 'PROGRAMDATA':
>   'C:\ProgramData', 'APPVEYOR_JOB_NUMBER': '1', 'AS': 'llvm-as', 'AR':
>   'llvm-ar', 'APPVEYOR_ACCOUNT_NAME': 'honnibal', 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK':
>   'NO', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\Program Files\Common Files',
>   'OLDPWD': 'C:/projects/cython-blis-h674r/flame-blis', 'DXSDK_DIR':
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\',
>   '7ZIP': '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"', 'PWD':
>   'C:/projects/cython-blis', 'CFLAGS': '-Wno-macro-redefined',
>   'UNIVERSALCRTSDKDIR': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\',
>   'VCINSTALLDIR': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\'}error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ```
>   clang -c C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c
> ```
>
> -o C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph04gz6ym\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o
>   -O3 -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.1" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\blis_src\include\windows-x86_64
>         ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c
>   'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7b1os69\blis\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v80ehmnh\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7eropvdx\normal'
>   --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\include\site\python3.7\blis'
>   Check the logs for full command output.
>   ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\scripts\python.exe'
>   'c:\users\leena\desktop\pythonfiles\genv\lib\site-packages\pip'
>   install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
>   'C:\Users\leena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7eropvdx\normal'
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython>=0.25' 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0'
>   'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2' 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2' wheel
>   'thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: spaCy dropped python 32bit support. Do i upgrade to 64bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue having same configuration 64 bit Windows 10 and 32 bit python 3.7+ .

Actually the problem is we can't build Blis with 32 bit python, so you have to use 64 bit python.

I have done the same and now it is working.

Check out official spacy issues (Reference) :- [Failed building wheel for blis when installing spacy-nightly through pip](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3019)

Answer (score 1):

Use:
 conda install -c conda-forge implicit

and then type

pip install -U spacy

Answer (score 0):

As for the wheel, you might have downloaded the wheel file for a different platform. Also, I am not sure why you are trying to flag '-U' though you are installing the package in a virtual environment. If your environment is active, try to install it without the flag and show the result.

Comment: You can get the compiled versions from here [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Try downloading the spacy version corresponding to your OS platform (x32 or x64). Can't test out on my machine because my OS architecture is 64 bit. For me the installation is smooth.

Comment: Even i have 64bit machine but my python is 32bit. I think spacy stopped support for that. Any method to directly upgrade? Or do I have to uninstall and install again?

Comment: You will have to uninstall 32 bit version and install 64 bit version.